# When will the new profile page be rolled out to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

It feels like we have been teased with the new site design for ages (way more than 6-8 weeks). What has happened to it? Way back in January, [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) was updated to show it would roll out in...6-8 weeks, but we are well past that point now.

The new page is already live on Meta.SE, so what are the plans for rolling out across the network, and most importantly to Stack Overflow?

Comment: you know that [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) is an inside joke of Stack Exchange, right?  So when they said that, they probably didn't actually mean 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Yes, I get the joke.

Comment: Just making sure since you seemed to be counting the weeks in your question.

Comment: I hope it will take them a very long time, I prefer the old one by far...

Comment: @l4mpi: I find myself actively missing the new features introduced on other sites.

Comment: I hope never. The current page is great.

Comment: @MartijnPieters for example? I don't use meta.SE at all, thus I didn't benefit from any new features. All I know is that the new social-media style profile page conflicts with my main use cases when visiting profiles of other users, and that I dislike the emphasis on profiles in general - after all, we're a knowledge repository, not a social media site.

Comment: @l4mpi: which is why a profile is the one place you can be a bit social. The badge progress indicators are *very* nice, and I'd love to see the impact value on SO if only to feed my narcissistic streak.

Comment: I agree, I also want the new badge progress indicators.

Comment: As I understand it, the reason why they haven't rolled it out other places is because they're still testing it – it hasn't actually "gone live" on Meta.SE in the sense that it's finalized (it's obviously up for everyone to use), but rather for testing on a (relatively) large pool of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is..........

TODAY!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1

Comment: <TINFOILHAT>
 The date of deployment seems to me a ploy to generate confusion in an election week.
</TINFOILHAT>